# Is it possible to use EXT4 partition in windows 10?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, sync, windows-10, github

This may seem like a noob question, most probably because it is.
I am currently on a dual-boot system with windows 10 and ubuntu 16.10.
I am syncing github sources to my hard disk on ubuntu(for building roms). The sources are are 25gb and with crappy internet speeds, takes days for me and there are times when I have to use windows.
So, is there any way I can view the partition in windows so that I can continue to sync the sources even when I'm using windows? 
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: this question is not about ubuntu, but about windows and its missing capability of accessing filesystems not developed by microsoft. please ask your question at "ServerFault".

Comment: Please use http://superuser.com/ for windows related questions

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use an ext partition with Windows on its own.

Windows cannot read ext partitions.  This has always been the case and continues to be the case.

You would have to repartition your disk to have a shared storage space (such as NTFS or FAT32) to use with both OSes and then use that for storing repositories you need on both environments.

---

@Rinzwind made a note in comments:

> There are at least 2 windows projects that allow using ext on windows. ext2fsd is for ext2 and ext3. Paragon ExtFS (non-free) allow full access to ext
>
> @AadithyaS ext2fsd is limited. it does not understand journaling and worse lacks ext4 support.

Comment: Well, that just blew a hole in my plans. But, I've heard of tools like Ext2Fsd , so these won't work well enough for my purpose ?

Comment: There are at least 2 windows projects that allow using ext on windows. `ext2fsd`  is for ext2 and ext3. `Paragon ExtFS` (non-free) allow full access to ext @AadithyaS ext2fsd is limited. it does not understand journaling  and worse lacks ext4 support.

Comment: I’m experimenting with BtrFS on a dual boot system with Linux and Windows. The BtrFS is /home & D: and all personal folders are symlinked to D:\duzun\* so that both systems share the storage for my stuff.