# How to acces to a ubuntu partition in my sata hdd from windows 10

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, windows-10

I have a bit old hdd hdd that has a ubuntu partition, now I want to use it as a external hdd with a sata adapter to connect it to a usb port in my laptop.

But I cant access that data because of the partition type.

What can I do?

Comment: basically asking the same as [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/848306/is-it-possible-to-use-ext4-partition-in-windows-10) is.  This is more or less offtopic - asking "HOw do I access Linux partitions in Windows" would be a SuperUser question.  (Read through the answers on the linked question, though)

Comment: Boot Ubuntu, backup data, and format as NTFS.